# Can't connect to Rails server running on EC2 from public IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently have been having a problem with my **AWS EC2** instances. The problem is that I cannot hit my Rails servers via public IP, but I can hit localhost and the server will respond.

Here's what I'm doing:

- Create new EC2 instance (t2.micro, ubuntu free tier)
- Security group has port 22, 80, 3000 open to everyone (0.0.0.0)
- SSH to EC2 instance, install rails (I've been using [this](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) to install)
- Start rails server after install, it's running on port 3000
- run "wget localhost:3000" and it returns index.html, yay!
- go to my web browser, type in EC2 instance public IP and port 3000 (IP:3000), says it can't connect :(
- kill rails server, restart it on port 80, wget works but can't connect via public IP
- as a sanity check, **I install nginx and run it, and can see the nginx start page on port 80 via public IP**... so confused...

So I'm thinking it has something to do with how I'm installing Rails, but I've tried methods other than using that install script but am encountering the same problem... I've even tried creating an entirely new AWS account just in case I screwed up the settings in my original account but haven't had any luck. I have previously been able to get rails running on EC2 instances just fine (in fact I have EC2 instances using the same security group running on my AWS account right now and can hit those public IPs just fine), but am now just banging my head against the wall... any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: For now, I've configured nginx to hit my rails server.... at least that works for now... although I'm still curious why I can't hit my rails server directly...

Comment: You likely also need to open Ubuntu's firewall to allow port 80 and/or 3000. http://serverfault.com/questions/574491/opening-port-80-on-ubuntu-aws

Comment: I ran `ufw status` and it says it's inactive. The output of `iptables -L` is as follows:
`root@ip-172-31-3-171:/home/ubuntu/blah# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check if rails listens on 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1, default is to listen only on localhost.

```
-b, --binding=IP                 Binds Rails to the specified IP.
                                 Default: localhost
```

From the [Ruby on Rails 4.2 Release Notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server):

> Due to a change in Rack, rails server now listens on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0 by default. This should have minimal impact on the standard development workflow as both http://127.0.0.1:3000 and http://localhost:3000 will continue to work as before on your own machine.

Comment: Running `bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0` actually solved my problem! Now I can hit my server just fine without using nginx... 

Did the default binding change in a recent release of Rail? A week ago I did not have this issue...

Comment: Has this changed some time ago? I don't remember that I had to set this option before.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using 'rails server' and want to use the default port 3000 then use below:

```
sudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

it can be accessed as `http://[public_ip]:3000`.

If you want to use it as a URL without the port use the below to run the server:

```
sudo rails server -p 80 -b 0.0.0.0
```

You just access it as `http://[public_ip]`.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the rails server on default port 3000 on my AWS Ubuntu instance and had allowed this port in the security group, inbound section but still I was unable to access my application by using this.
http://public_ip:3000

I searched a lot and this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/574491/opening-port-80-on-ubuntu-aws#answer-574502) helped me. Explaining the answer. We have to make firewall setting flexible so that our firewall allows port 3000.

You can use this command to check if this port is allowed on firewall or not.

```
$ sudo iptables -L | grep :3000
```

If you see nothing it means we have to allow it using this command.

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

This worked for me to get my rails app access on port 3000.